# Pandas read_csv function cuts off html link with three dots

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have exported a data from a website containing multiple html links into a CSV file. I wanted to load this file to Python ad df to further work on it, however I have noticed that the links are cut off and end with "...", making them invalid. In the CSV file the links are perfectly correct. I assume there is some underlying condition that limits the length of a string imported into a data frame. Could you please help me with the issue? It seems trivial, but I was banging my head against the wall for a two hours now. [image: Screenshot]

Comment: How did you check that? Have you used Jupyter by any chance?

Comment: Could you provide a reproducible example?

Comment: Yes, I am using Jupyter Notebook. I am simply reading csv file and then choosing column with brackets (['...']). However, the links are cut off from certain point with "..." and hence do not work. When opened with Excel the file works perfectly fine and the links are fully preserved.

Comment: I have added the screenshot in the original post.

Comment: Have you tried my solution? Was the way Jupyter displays text the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with the data, the links are not trimmed. What you see is Jupyter Notebook adjusting what is displayed to fit information on the display.

You can override the default behaviour and set the max number of characters yourself with:

```
pd.set_option('display.width', 666)
```

See the [set_option](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.set_option.html) for reference.

Comment: Thanks, that solved the problem, forgot to tag the response as "solving" :)